# Is the following logic distribution correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification, substitution

Did I do the following distribution correctly?:

```
(p Λ ~q) V (q Λ ~r) <=> (p V q) Λ (p V ~r) Λ (~q Λ q) Λ (~q Λ ~r)
                    <=> (p V q) Λ (p V ~r) Λ FALSE Λ (~q Λ ~r)
                    <=> FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(p Λ ~q) V (q Λ ~r) <=> (p V q) Λ (p V ~r) Λ (~q V q) Λ (~q V ~r)
                    <=> (p V q) Λ (p V ~r) Λ TRUE Λ (~q V ~r)
                    <=> (p V q) Λ (p V ~r) Λ (~q V ~r)
```